# How to create the CXFServlet?

Tags: java, servlets, cxf

Prior to `cxf-3.1.0` one could use `new org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet()` to instantiate the servlet, or via `web.xml` configuration:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>
       org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
  </servlet>
```

But now when I upgrade to 3.1.0, the class cannot be found anymore.

How could the the servlet be created with cxf?

Comment: according to javadoc for 3.1.0 it is still there https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transport/servlet/CXFServlet.html . can you find it in your JAR files? what error do you get?

Comment: The import could not be found. Maybe the class mved to a different dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a simple spring boot application that works correctly with CXFServlet - here is the extract from pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>demo.DemoApplication</start-class>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <cxf.version>3.1.0</cxf.version>
</properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I simply create new servlet like

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"classpath:/cxf-servlet.xml" })
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet cxfServlet = new org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean servletDef = new ServletRegistrationBean(cxfServlet, "/cxf/*");
        servletDef.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletDef;
    }
}
```

Comment: `cxf-rt-transports-http` came as part of `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws` up to `3.0.5`, but as of now one has to add the dependency explicit. Thanks!